# Why a simple POST takes too long?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am running tests on a site which will be online next week and i have a strange situation.

On [this](http://213.133.103.5/gramma_prod/Site/DetaliiProdus.aspx?category=m1&productId=778&subcategory1Id=41&subcategory2Id=72) page i have 4 Tabs where **'Prezentare'** is loaded by Default.
Well, i do not understand why, when i press on **'Descopera'**  the POST to the server **takes 6 seconds !!!** (used firebug to investigate) Please note that no queries are running behing that POST only a div is hidden and another is made visible...

Do you have any clue?

I have a dedicated server:
Single core AMD Athlon 64 3700+
2 GB

Thanks in advance...

**Edit:** the tabs are within an update panel and the Tabs' names are link buttons which OnClick event show the corresponding div and hide the others

Code for Tabs:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="updatePanelTabs">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <ul class="meniu prezentare" runat="server" id="ulTabs">
                <li>
                    <asp:LinkButton OnClick="lnkTab_Click" ID="lnkPrezentare" runat="server">Prezentare
                 </asp:LinkButton>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <asp:LinkButton OnClick="lnkTab_Click" ID="lnkRecenzie" runat="server">Recenzie
                 </asp:LinkButton>
                <li>
                    <asp:LinkButton OnClick="lnkTab_Click" ID="lnkComentarii" runat="server">Comentarii
                 </asp:LinkButton>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <asp:LinkButton OnClick="lnkTab_Click" ID="lnkDescopera" runat="server">Descopera
                 </asp:LinkButton>
                </li>
// other code
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

What OnClick method is doing:

```
 protected void lnkTab_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton lnkPressed = (LinkButton)sender;
        switch (lnkPressed.ID.ToString())
        {
            case "lnkPrezentare":
                {
                    ulTabs.Attributes.Add("class", "meniu prezentare");
                    hideRestTabs("lnkPrezentare");
                    break;
                }
            case "lnkRecenzie":
                {
                    ulTabs.Attributes.Add("class", "meniu recenzie");
                    hideRestTabs("lnkRecenzie");
                    break;
                }
            case "lnkComentarii":

                {
                    ulTabs.Attributes.Add("class", "meniu comentarii");
                    hideRestTabs("lnkComentarii");
                    break;
                }
            case "lnkDescopera":
                {
                    ulTabs.Attributes.Add("class", "meniu descopera");
                    hideRestTabs("lnkDescopera");
                    break;
                }
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE:** It seems that it depends on internet connection for me. I have friends which tested and for they the "switching tabs" takes 1.5 s...

Comment: tested and the time looks okay for me. 6 is not okay?

Comment: IMHO, a simple ajax request of 6 seconds seems too much for me

Comment: How is that programmed? The POST.... is done how? How you gnerate the new page without processing the whole page? There are various approaches - some render the complete page again (update panel) and only transmit the part changing.

Comment: Hi Tom. The tabs are within an update panel and the Tabs' names are link buttons which OnClick event shows the corresponding div and hides the others...

Comment: BTW, do not understand why others are voting this question to be closed...

Comment: It indeed takes a long time to roundtrip; perhaps the connection is sluggish. 
Looking at the page though, there is not that much information on the tabs to justify an AJAX call except for the "post comment" function - why don't you keep the page static unless the "post comment" reload.

Comment: Voted to close because you've provided no code within your question as to what the AJAX call is doing client side and server side. Only took 3 and a bit seconds on my machine anyway.

Answer (score 0):

see if by any chance you've used System.Threading.Thread.Sleep() in your asp.net source code for testing ajax requests?

Comment: Hmm..On this page not. Only when i generate tags on other page but that code is not "touched" when this page is rendered.